# radius of convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n^{\frac1n}-1)x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Find the radius of convergence $R$ for the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n^{\frac1n}-1)x^n$$

Applying the ratio test, this becomes $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}-1}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}$, which is $\dfrac00$ and seems hard to use L'Hospital.

Applying the root test, this becomes $\limsup (n^{\frac1n}-1)^{\frac1n}$, and I don't know what that is.

Comment: The first test is the ratio test and the second is the root test.

Comment: Take logs of both sides, use the fact that $lim_{x\to\infty}e^{\ln{f(x)}}=e^{lim_{x\to\infty}\ln f(x)}$

Comment: The radius of convergence is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $$n^{1/n}=e^{\frac 1 n\log n}$$

For large $n$, (that is, near the origin for $e^x$, since $n^{-1}\log n\to 0$) we can then write $$n^{1/n}=1+\frac{\log n}{n}+\frac{\log^2n}{n^2}+O(n^{-2})$$ since for large enough $n$, $$\frac{\log^3n}{n^3}\leq \frac 1 {n^2}$$so $$n^{1/n}-1=\frac{\log n}{n}+\frac{\log^2n}{n^2}+O(n^{-2})$$
Can you take it from here?